# Detect user login/logout xmpp google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xmpp

I am using Google App Engine in Java to send XMPP messages.

I would like to know if there is a way to check if a user is logged in to the system or logged out. So, when the user signs in, I would like to send him a *welcome* chat message and when he signs out I would like to notify my server code of the same.

I have tried the presence API but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to querying a user's *presence* via XMPP, keep in mind that this will *only* work if your App Engine account is *authorized* by that user. If you have already got that far, querying for presence (user logged in/logged out) is quite simple ([source](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview.html#Handling_User_Presence)).

If a Google talk user has subscribed to an app (has accepted an invitation or has invited the app to chat), the app can discover the user's availability by looking for a POST to `/_ah/xmpp/presence/available`. If the user is subscribed and available, you can send them your application's presence and status:

```
// In the handler for _ah/xmpp/presence/available
XMPPService xmppService = XMPPServiceFactory.getXMPPService();
Presence presence = xmppService.parsePresence(req);

// Split the XMPP address (e.g., user@gmail.com)
// from the resource (e.g., gmail.CD6EBC4A)
String from = presence.getFromJid().getId().split("/")[0];

// Mirror the contact's presence back to them
xmppService.sendPresence(from, PresenceType.AVAILABLE, presence.getPresenceShow(), presence.getStatus());
```

**To further clarify**, your app receives *automatic* presence notifications via the following POST URL paths:

- POSTs to `/_ah/xmpp/presence/available/` signal that the user is **available** and provide the user's chat status.
- POSTs to `/_ah/xmpp/presence/unavailable/` signal that the user is **unavailable**.
- POSTs to `/_ah/xmpp/presence/probe/` **request** a user's current presence.

As an example, when user *sally* logs in, you'll get a POST request to `/_ah/xmpp/presence/available/` which your server will then have to process. Then when *sally* logs out, you'll get a separate POST request to `/_ah/xmpp/presence/unavailable/`.

Comment: I am trying this. Do I get a presence notification when the user signs out from, say GTalk?

Comment: You will get a presence notification if the user's presence changes _across all their IM clients_. So if a user is signed in from gmail and their android phone, say, and they close their gmail window, you won't (necessarily, with some caveats related to capabilities) get a presence notification.

Comment: Okay. It makes more sense to me now. Thanks. Also, would the GTalk client continuously send Available notifications to /_ah/xmpp/presence/available? I see it sends after every 6 mins.

Comment: @Joy Experiment with that and let us know :)

Comment: Okay. Is this because a client can publish presence to any number of Topic Servers?  Ref: http://www.adarshr.com/papers/xmpp2